# Swift NavBar Hide NavBarItem

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Inside of my view controller I have a navBar with an item on the left side and right side. I also have 2 buttons inside of the view controller. I have it so each button does different functionality. I also have the swift file connected to the view.

My issue is that when I do either of the code below inside of my button actions the NavBar Items do not change. I don't know how to remove and add the item back, I also dont understand what Im doing wrong.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: And how you have added those buttons in `UINavigationBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect Navigation Bar from storyboard to View Controller Class

```
@IBOutlet var navBar: UINavigationBar!
```

This will hide Button

```
navBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
navBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

This will show Button

```
navBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
navBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i can't make comment due to low reputetion. Which IDE are you using?

The answer of @dharmesh works, if you create the button programmatically:

```
    let btn = UIButton(type: .system)
    btn.setTitle("Indietro", for: btn.state)
    
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(annulla), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn)
```

If you use the one from the IDE it depends on the IDE itself to store the values to hide or change it